# Server Internet Connection Only Google

Tags: iis, restart

My server sometimes internet connection allows only google's web sites  for others there is no connection.But i restart iis everyting is well and there is no problem.

Comment: Which Windows version and which Windows Edition do you use ? (e.g Windows Server 2008 R2) Which IIS version ? Is this a freshly installed server ? What have installed and configured so far ?

Comment: Windows server 2012 R2 .IIS 6.0 and fresh installed.Extra plesk added.